# How do i increase the config.vm.boot_timeout in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrant-windows

I am trying to install vagrant on my windows pc.The vagrant version is 2.3.0 along with the oracle vm. i keep getting this error anytime i run vagrant up. i want to try  increasing the timeout but have no idea how to.This is how the error looks like:

````
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.```
````

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, from the tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

Comment: Can you provide your `Vagrantfile`? That is where you would [configure the timeout](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings)

Answer (score 0):

```
 # -*- mode: ruby -*-
```

## vi: set ft=ruby :

`````
    # All Vagrant configuration is done below. The 
    "2" in Vagrant.configure
    # configures the configuration version (we 
    support older styles for
    # backwards compatibility). Please don't change 
    it unless you know what
    # you're doing.
    Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # The most common configuration options are 
    documented and commented below.
    # For a complete reference, please see the 
    online documentation at
    # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

    # Every Vagrant development environment requires 
     a box. You can search for
    # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"

    # Disable automatic box update checking. If you 
    disable this, then
    # boxes will only be checked for updates when 
    the user runs
    # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not 
    recommended.
    # config.vm.box_check_update = false

     # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows 
     access to a specific port
     # within the machine from a port on the host 
     machine. In the example below,
     # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 
     80 on the guest machine.
     # NOTE: This will enable public access to the 
     opened port
     # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 
     80, host: 8080

     # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows 
     access to a specific port
     # within the machine from a port on the host 
    machine and only allow access
    # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
     # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 
    80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

    # Create a private network, which allows host- 
    only access to the machine
    # using a specific IP.
    # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: 
     "192.168.33.10"

     # Create a public network, which generally 
      matched to bridged network.
     # Bridged networks make the machine appear as 
     another physical device on
     # your network.
     # config.vm.network "public_network"

     # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. 
     The first argument is
     # the path on the host to the actual folder. 
     The second argument is
     # the path on the guest to mount the folder. 
     And the optional third
     # argument is a set of non-required options.
     # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", 
     "/vagrant_data"

     # Provider-specific configuration so you can 
     fine-tune various
     # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose 
     provider-specific options.
      # Example for VirtualBox:
     #
     # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting 
     the machine
     #   vb.gui = true
     #
     #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     #   vb.memory = "1024"
     # end
     #
     # View the documentation for the provider you 
     are using for more
     # information on available options.

     # Enable provisioning with a shell script. 
     Additional provisioners such as
     # Ansible, Chef, Docker, Puppet and Salt are 
     also available. Please see the
     # documentation for more information about 
     their specific syntax and use.
      # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<- 
     SHELL
      #   apt-get update
      #   apt-get install -y apache2
      # SHELL
      end ````
`````